# Getting "Cannot access empty property" when using PHP Mailer

Tags: php

I'm getting this error message trying to use PHP Mailer.  Please let me know if you see what is wrong.

```
Fatal error: Cannot access empty property in /hsphere/local/home/c263430/quoralist.com/includes/phpmailer/phpmailer.inc.php on line 271
```

Line 271 of phpmailer.inc.php is

```
$header[] = sprintf("Content-Transfer-Encoding: %s\n", $this->$Encoding);
```

The code that called phpmailer.inc.php is

```
<?php

require_once("../includes/phpmailer/phpmailer.inc.php");
require_once("../includes/phpmailer/smtp.inc.php");
$to_name = "Junk Mail";
$to = "m73mit@gmail.com";
$subject = "Mail Test at ".strftime("%T", time());
$message = "This is a test.";
$message = wordwrap($message, 70);
$from_name = "Michael Mitchell";
$from = "michaeljohnmitchell@gmail.com";

//Php mail version (default)
$mail = new PHPMailer();

//$mail->IsSMTP();
//$mail->Host   = "host"
//$mail->Port       = 25;
//$mail->SMTPAuth   = false;
//$mail->Username   = "username";
//$mail->Password   = "password";


$mail->FromName = $from_name;
$mail->From     = $from;
$mail->AddAddress($to, $to_name);
$mail->Subject  = $subject;
$mail->Body     = $message;

$result = $mail->Send();

echo $result ? 'Sent' : 'Error';


?>
```

EDIT

following a suggestion in one of the answers, I tried `$this->Encoding` instead of `$this->$Encoding`.  When I ran it I got a new error message, not sure if it's related.

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare class SMTP in /hsphere/local/home/c263430/quoralist.com/includes/phpmailer/smtp.inc.php on line 26
```

The class at line 26 of smtp.inc.php is

```
class SMTP {
        var $SMTP_PORT = 25; # the default SMTP PORT
        var $CRLF = "\r\n";  # CRLF pair

        var $smtp_conn;      # the socket to the server
        var $error;          # error if any on the last call
        var $helo_rply;      # the reply the server sent to us for HELO

        var $do_debug;       # the level of debug to perform
```

Comment: @Michael have you tried downloading a newer version of PHP Mailer?

Comment: I downloaded it today. It was their php5/6 download. Do you know of another version i should download?

Comment: @Michael by the look of it, for some reason the encoding of the message is not being set

Comment: Make sure you don't have a line like `class SMTP` anywhere else in your code, and make sure you always use `require_once` to include the file smtp.inc.php

Comment: @Mark Eirich thanks, that's not the problem.

Comment: The error "Cannot redeclare class SMTP" means that either smtp.inc.php is included more than once, or you have defined another class named SMTP.

Comment: @Mark Eirich ..well, the "Cannot redeclare class SMTP" error appeared after I changed $this->$Encoding (as specified in OP) to $this->Encoding, as described in the answer below. Do you accept this suggestion as part of the answer? I'm not sure if the SMTP error would appear the $this->$Encoding hadn't been changed? or would it have appeared anyways?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this line:

```
$header[] = sprintf("Content-Transfer-Encoding: %s\n", $this->$Encoding);
```

Change it to this:

```
$header[] = sprintf("Content-Transfer-Encoding: %s\n", $this->Encoding);
```

Answer (score 4):

try to write $this->Encoding

accessing member variables does not require an additional $ sign.

In addition I show you here my mail class from my old framework.

```
class Utils_EMail  {
    public static function sendMail($subject,$msg,$to = ADMIN_EMAIL_ADRESS){
        $headers = "Mime-Version: 1.0 \n";
        $headers .= "Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8 \n";
        $headers .= "From: ".mb_encode_mimeheader(HTTP_HOST,"UTF-8","AUTO")."<".SYSTEM_EMAIL_ADRESS."> \n";
        $subject = mb_convert_encoding($subject,"UTF-8","AUTO");
        $msg    = mb_convert_encoding($msg,"UTF-8","AUTO");
        mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); 
        mb_send_mail($to,$subject,$msg,$headers);
    }
}
```

Comment: Depends how the variable is declared

Comment: I tried it, but then got a different error message, don't know if it's related. I'll update the OP with the info.

Comment: Furthermore, if I would rewrite this now, I would use '' instead of "" because '' brings more performance, when not needing a line break like \n. because line breaks require "" quotation marks.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact error. Check what version of PHPMailer you're using.
I downloaded Version 5/6 from sourceforge.net and somehow ended up with the original version from 2001.

Get the latest one from here:

http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/phpmailer/downloads/list